# Fix Javascript Value to 0 decimals

Tags: javascript

I have this script which is working in formatting my currency but now its not fixing my value to 0 decimal places, Im new to javascript so could anybody explain where and hwo I'd do this? Thanks

```
function FormatNumberBy3(num, decpoint, sep) {
  // check for missing parameters and use defaults if so
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    sep = ",";
  }
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    sep = ",";
    decpoint = ".";
  }
  // need a string for operations
  num = num.toString();
  // separate the whole number and the fraction if possible
  a = num.split(decpoint);
  x = a[0]; // decimal
  y = a[1]; // fraction
  z = "";


  if (typeof(x) != "undefined") {
    // reverse the digits. regexp works from left to right.
    for (i=x.length-1;i>=0;i--)
      z += x.charAt(i);
    // add seperators. but undo the trailing one, if there
    z = z.replace(/(\d{3})/g, "$1" + sep);
    if (z.slice(-sep.length) == sep)
      z = z.slice(0, -sep.length);
    x = "";
    // reverse again to get back the number
    for (i=z.length-1;i>=0;i--)
      x += z.charAt(i);
    // add the fraction back in, if it was there
    if (typeof(y) != "undefined" && y.length > 0)
      x += decpoint + y;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `toFixed` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)? Maybe it can help...

Comment: I've used .toFixed but it seems to claseh with the above...

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you want Math.floor()

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathfunc.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can round numbers mathematically, which is much, much faster and much, much, much simpler. There are literally hundreds of examples of this algorithm all over this site alone.

```
function round(number, places)
{
    var multiplicator = Math.pow(10, places);
    return Math.round(number * multiplicator) / multiplicator;
}

alert(round(123.456, 0)); // alerts "123"
```

This function lets you round to an arbitrary decimal place. If you want to round to the nearest integer, you may simply use `Math.round(x)`.

`Math.round` rounds a decimal number to the nearest integer. Assuming you want to keep *3* decimal places, all you have to do is multiply the decimal number by 1000 (which is 10 power *3*), round to the nearest integer, then divide by 1000. This is what this snippet does.

Comment: Ahhh, I need to add commas after the thousands so I dont think this would work

Answer (score 0):

Your function appears to work for me... I assume the result of passing `"1000"` as an argument should be `"1,000"`? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "fixing [your] value to 0 decimal places".

Here's a function I wrote to format numbers (like your above function does) for an API once:

```
function num_format(str) {
    if (typeof str !== 'string' || /[^\d,\.e+-]/.test(str)) {
        if (typeof str === 'number') {
            str = str.toString();
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("Argument is not a string with a number in it");
        }
    }
    var reg = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    str = str.split(".");
    while (reg.test(str[0])) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(reg, "$1,$2");
    }
    return str.join(".");
}
```

Remove the error checking code and it becomes quite a short little function (five lines). Pass it any number and it will format it correctly, although I didn't allow the option of specifying the separators.

As for rounding numbers to arbitrary decimal places, I suggest seeing [zneak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126881/fix-javascript-value-to-0-decimals/6126962#6126962) above. Then would simply do:

```
num_format(round("100000.12341234", 2));
```

Which would give a result of `"100,000.12"`.

Answer (score 0):

This function should be capable of all various scenarios:

```
function formatNumber(num, precision, sep, thousand, addTrailing0) {
    if (isNaN(num))
        return "";
    if (isNaN(precision))
        precision = 2;
    if (typeof addTrailing0 == "undefined")
        addTrailing0 = true;

    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    num = String(Math.round(num * factor) / factor);

    if (addTrailing0 && precision > 0) {
        if (num.indexOf(".") < 0)
            num += ".";
        for (var length = num.substr(num.indexOf(".")+1).length; length < precision; ++length)
            num += "0";
    }

    var parts = num.split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + (thousand || ",")).split("").reverse().join("");

    num = parts[0] + (parts.length > 1 ? (sep || ".") + parts[1] : "");

    //debug:
    document.write(num + "<br />");

    return num;
}
```

Examples:

```
formatNumber(32432342342.3574, 0);             // 32,432,342,342
formatNumber(32432342342.3574, 2);             // 32,432,342,342.36
formatNumber(1342.525423, 4, ".", ",");        //          1,342.5254
formatNumber(1342.525423, 2, ",", ".");        //          1.342,53
formatNumber(1342.525423);                     //          1,342.53
formatNumber(1342.525423, 0);                  //          1,343
formatNumber(342.525423, 8);                   //            342.52542300
formatNumber(42.525423, 8, null, null, false); //             42.525423
formatNumber(2.5, 3, ",", ".");                //              2,500
```

Working Live Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/xCqqh/